# Finding the nth string in a delimited string

Tags: java, android

Does anyone have any idea how to find the n-th field (string) in a delimited string where the delimiters (separator) could be either a single char or several chars.

For instance,

```
string = "one*two*three"

separator = "*"
```

and the syntax for user-defined function is `FindNthField(string,separator,position)`

so position 3 would return `three`

The separator in use would actually be `Chr(13)`.

This has to run on Android and so should be efficient.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thank you very much - all three examples worked first time.

Comment: i found a reference to a now deprecated Java funtion - peekNthDelimitedField(java.lang.String string, char separator, int nth, boolean trim) 
  Treats the given string as a separator delimited string, and returns the nth field from this string.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
public String FindNthField(String string, String separator, int position) {
    String[] splits = string.split(separator);
    if (splits.length < position) {
        return null;
    }

    return splits[position - 1];
}
```

Obviously, your `separator` must be a `regex` string and I didn't do the `null` check(s).

Comment: @Andreas_D, I actually copied the OP's method...but I can easily rename it if you want.

Comment: (@Gentlemen - yeah, sorry, commented first, then saw that the name was copied, then deleted my comment ;) - all within one minute )

Comment: @Andreas_D, no sweat...now, my previous comment looks weird as it seems I'm replying to a ghost comment... :)

Answer (score 0):

`String#split` is your friend:

```
private String findNthField(String input, int position) {
  return findNthField(input, "\n", position);
}

private String findNthField(String input, String regExp, int lineNr) {
  if (input == null || regExp == null || regExp.equals(""))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("your message");

  String[] parts = input.split(regExp);
  if (parts.length < lineNr) 
       return "";                 // local convention

  return parts[lineNr-1];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the very fast response it helped me understand string split.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitterTest {
    @Test
    public void testFindNthField() {
        final Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
        Assert.assertEquals("result", "three", splitter.findNthField("one*two*three", '*', 3));
    }

    private class Splitter {
        public String findNthField(final String input, final char separator, final int position) {
            final List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
            final char[] chars = new char[input.length()];
            input.getChars(0, input.length(), chars, 0);
            int wordStart = 0;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < chars.length; idx++) {
                if (chars[idx] == separator) {
                    parts.add((String) input.subSequence(wordStart, idx));
                    wordStart = idx + 1;
                }
            }
            parts.add(input.substring(wordStart));
            return parts.get(position - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer based on String.split() but saw that the OP wanted to use a Character splitter, so I changed it.

Comment: I've timed this and compared it with the other two string separator examples and it works twice as fast although of course they can cope with string separators. I'll use both versions - thank you

Comment: @Malkoma: any chance you could accept either this or another one then? And maybe an upvote if you're using it?